# Create a string in C with a format specifier

Tags: c, string

Is there a standard C function that allows you to build strings using format specifiers?

Right now I'm doing this:

```
char buffer[256];
char *name = "Fred";
strcpy(buffer, "Hello, ");
strcat(buffer, name);
strcat(buffer, ". How are you today?\n");
```

Is there a way to add the message to buffer in one function?

Something like this:

```
makestr(buffer, "Hello, %s. How are you today?\n", name);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/)

Be careful when using it because sprintf is not a safe function and can suffer from [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#Buffer_safety_and_sprintf).

Comment: I would upvote this answer were it not for the ridiculous contention that sprintf is not safe. It's perfectly safe if you know what you're doing and people that don't know what they're doing should probably be using BASIC instead of C :-)

Comment: Do you recommend snprintf to avoid the risk of buffer overflow?

Answer (score 1):

Would **sprintf** be helpful to you? Link:
[sprintf](http://www.cppreference.com/stdio/sprintf.html)